# ReasonML binding function with config having fixed string values

Tags: ffi, reason, bucklescript

Lets say, that I have this function in Javascript which can generate string based on proper configuration:

```
function func(config) {
  // ...
}
```

also, let's assume, that the `config` variable has structure as below (all of these can be not given to function call):

```
{
  "color": string,  // can be: "blue", "red", "green"
  "number": int,    // can be: any number
  "other": string,  // can be: "x", "y"
}
```

How to create proper binding for this? I'm stuck with:

```
[@bs.deriving abstract]
type options = {
  [@bs.optional]
  color: [@bs.string] [ | `blue | `red | `green ]
  [@bs.optional]
  number: int,
  [@bs.optional]
  other: [@bs.string] [ | `x | `y ]
}

[@bs.module]
external func: options => string = "func";
```

But it does not work when trying to use like this:

```
let config = MyModule.config(
  ~color=`blue,
  ~number=123,
  ~other=`x
);

let value = MyModule.func(config);
```

The `color` and `other` values are integers, not strings.

Comment: There's several bugs in your example code: 1. There's a missing comma at the end of the `color` field definition, and 2. The call to `MyModule.config`, which technically also should be `MyModule.options`, is partially applied because it's missing the final `unit` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case of a JavaScript idiom for named parameters (objects with optional fields), needing to be adapted to the OCaml/ReasonML idiom (functions with actual labelled parameters). You would do this in three steps. Step 1, as Glenn showed, define an external for the config:

```ml
type config;
[@bs.obj] external config: (
  ~color:[@bs.string] [`blue | `red | `green]=?,
  ~number:int=?,
  ~other:[@bs.string] [`x | `y]=?,
 unit,
) => config = "";
```

Step 2, bind to the JavaScript function using the JavaScript style of the config object:

```ml
[@bs.val] external func: config => string = "";
```

Step 3, wrap the JavaScript function binding in an OCaml-idiomatic function with labelled parameters:

```ml
let func(~color=?, ~number=?, ~other=?, ()) = ()
  |> config(~color?, ~number?, ~other?)
  |> func;
```

You can use it like this:

```ml
let result = func(~color=`blue, ());
```

Answer (score 1):

The `@bs` attributes are often poorly thought out hacks that you shouldn't expect to work well with other attributes, or really with anything other than exactly what the documentation explains or shows examples of. However, if an attribute is used where it is not intended you'll usually at least get a warning about the attribute being unused, which your code does.

`@bs.string` in particular only works on types at the outermost level of externals, i.e. on types whose values will be passed directly to the external function. There is also a way to create JavaScript objects using external functions which also happens to use less magic and give you much more control over the API. As far as I'm aware, the only downside compared to `@bs.deriving` is that you can't override field names using something like `@bs.as`. They have to be valid OCaml identifiers.

Here's your example implemented using an external function annotated with `@bs.obj`:

```rust
type options;
[@bs.obj] external options : (
  ~color:[@bs.string] [`blue | `red | `green]=?,
  ~number:int=?,
  ~other:[@bs.string] [`x | `y]=?,
  unit
  ) => options = "";
```

To use it you call it exactly as with `@bs.deriving`:

```rust
let config = options(~color=`blue,~number=123, ~other=`x, ());
```

But even with this I've encountered edge cases where integer values are passed in instead of strings. For this reason I tend to avoid the polymorphic variant attributes altogether and instead use ordinary variants along with conversion functions. This has the added benefit of being more idiomatic, blending in better and being more interoperable with non-BuckleScript code.

Here's what your example might look like using this approach:

```rust
type color = Blue | Red | Green;
let colorToString = fun
  | Blue => "blue"
  | Red => "red"
  | Green => "green";

type other = X | Y;    
let otherToString = fun
  | X => "x"
  | Y => "y";

[@bs.obj] external options : (
  ~color:string=?,
  ~number:int=?,
  ~other:string=?,
  unit
  ) => options = "";

[@bs.module] external func: options => string = "func";

let func = (~color=?, ~number=?, ~other=?, ()) =>
    func(options(
      ~color = ?Belt.Option.map(color, colorToString),
      ~number?,
      ~other = ?Belt.Option.map(other, otherToString),
      ()));

let config = func(~color=Blue,~number=123, ~other=X, ());
```

Comment: It indeed looks like polymorphic variants don't need to be used in those types of examples. Thank you for your response! I'm implementing new binding for randomColor library and used your version, for now: [LINK](https://github.com/ktrzos/bs-randomColor/blob/master/src/RandomColorRe.re)

Comment: @KrzysztofTrzos one thing to be aware of with this approach is that BuckleScript may not be able to optimize out all the conversion functions out. With the polymorphic variants approach, you 'pay for for you use'.

Comment: @Yawar So what is the cost of this solution and what issues can it bring?

Comment: @Yawar I would go even further and say it very likely won't, unless you're doing everything in a single module. But it's at least sound. That's why I use this approach for `bs-webapi` and `bs-fetch`, which are intended as low-level bindings and otherwise a good fit for `@bs.string` had it worked properly. There are other ways of reducing the overhead, however, such as using constants instead of variants like I do in [bs-fetch#next](https://github.com/reasonml-community/bs-fetch/tree/next/src), but then you sacrifice exhaustiveness checking... Unfortunately there is no simple answer here.

Comment: Also, if bsc had been a little bit smarter it could have compiled the conversion functions into some pretty compact lookup tables.

Comment: @glennsl is the unsoundness a known issue? I haven't come across it before.

Comment: @Yawar No idea, and it might have been fixed since, but it was still there around the time I made the bs-fetch#next branch at least. My advice is just to proceed with caution and not go all in on it immediately

Comment: Looking through the bs-fetch source for what might have caused it I came across another consideration though: `@bs.string` does not work with `@bs.get`, so If you want to not just create the object but access its properties as well, you'll still need to write conversion functions.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in reality, those values are **[variants](https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/variant)**, instead of trying to make it exactly like JavaScript, I would rather try something more idiomatic to Reason:

```ml
type color = Blue | Green | Red;
type coords = X | Y;
type config = {
  color,
  coords,
  number: int
};

let func = (config: config) => "something"
```

And then inside your function actually return strings (if that is what you really need) by pattern matching on the correct values provided to `config`.

See the working code [here](https://reasonml.github.io/en/try?rrjsx=true&reason=C4TwDgpgBAxg9gGzgJygXigIQQV2gHygHFkIIA7KQgJQgBMBuAKFEljhToGd0oANKlACazVtHjkAZgEsA5rwDeTKOyTIANMvacumleRwBbAEYRkALijTywJgF9mTBBGBRJOcjF4AKCTNmWfnIAlOgAfFAARFxwhi4AFtaykUA).

Hope it helps!